# How to override TokenController for FOSOAuthServerBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, controller

I followed Symfony's cookbook on how to override bundle controller, but for some reason I can't get it working.

My `OAuth` bundle is a child of `FOSOAuthServerBundle`. My `TokenController` is declared as class TokenController extends `\FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Controller\TokenController`. But for some reason I still get parent controller executed, instead of my own controller (child). When I alter routing manually to point `/oauth/v2/token` to my `TokenController` directly, I get it executing, but with an 500 error:

> Argument 1 passed to FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Controller\TokenController::__construct() must be an instance of OAuth2\OAuth2, none given, called in /.../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerResolver.php on line 78 and defined (500 Internal Server Error)

Why? I am puzzled. What's wrong? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What Mick said is true. To follow up on <kbd>3</kbd> (overriding a service), read on.

In `app/config/services.yml`, add the following:

```
services:
    fos_oauth_server.controller.token:
        class: OAuth2Bundle\Controller\TokenController
        arguments: [@fos_oauth_server.server]
```

Where `OAuth2Bundle\Controller\TokenController` is your custom controller extending the one from the FOS bundle.

For example:

```
namespace OAuth2Bundle\Controller;

use FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Controller\TokenController as BaseController;
use OAuth2\OAuth2;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class TokenController extends BaseController {

    public function tokenAction(Request $request)
    {
        // Do whatever you like here

        $result = parent::tokenAction($request);

        // More custom code.

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Of course, you can do whatever you like with `$result`. You can even omit the `parent::` call and perform your own authentication to return a token.

**EDIT**

This is a follow up on the above. I had to access some entities and do some updates when a user would receive a token. This required me to have access to the entity manager. In my case I had to check if the OAuth client is still active; it isn't deleted, but just temporarily disabled to block a group of users.

Because the controller is a service, you can add extra parameters like the entity manager:

The service definition now looks like this:

```
fos_oauth_server.controller.token:
  class: ApiBundle\Controller\OAuth\TokenController
  arguments: [@fos_oauth_server.server, @doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

And of course the controller now has a constructor. It now looks like this:

```
namespace OAuth2Bundle\Controller;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Controller\TokenController as BaseController;
use OAuth2\OAuth2;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class TokenController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * @param OAuth2 $server
     */
    public function __construct(OAuth2 $server, EntityManager $entityManager )
    {
        parent::__construct($server);
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

    public function tokenAction(Request $request)
    {
        // Do whatever you like here

        $result = parent::tokenAction($request);

        // More custom code.

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: With your "EDIT" part: Argument 1 passed to OAuthTokenController::__construct() must be an instance of OAuth2\\OAuth2, none given, called in app/cache/dev/classes.php on line 2214 and defined". Argument passed is @fos_oauth_server.server. I don't understand why none is given.

Comment: Did you clear your cache after updating `services.yml`? The service is defined in this file: `/vendor/friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle/FOS/OAuthServerBundle/Resources/config/oauth.xml`. It is a FOS service so it should exist.

Answer (score 1):

**A few thoughts:**

<kbd>1</kbd> Did you declare your bundle in `AppKernel.php`?

```
$bundles = array(
        ...
        new Acme\OAuthServerBundle()
    );
```

<kbd>2</kbd> As you can see in [oauth.xml](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/oauth.xml#L21-L28) and in the [Controller class](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Controller/TokenController.php#L25-31), the controller expects the server OAuth2 in its constructor. So if you override the constructor, make sure to include 'use OAuth2\OAuth2;' at the top of your file.

<kbd>3</kbd>
Since the controller is used as a service, you might have to override `oauth.xml` to redefine the class to use for that service.

Comment: How will you override oauth.xml?

Comment: See [How to override any part of a bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html)